# GROUP BY HAVING not working as expected

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, having

I'm struggling with what should be a simple query.

An event table stores user activity in an application.  Each click generates a new event and datetime stamp.  I need to show a list of recently accessed records having the most recent datetime stamp.  I need to only show the past 7 days of activity.

The table has an auto-increment field (eventID), which corresponds with the date_event field, so it's better to use that for determining the most recent record in the group.

I found that some records are not appearing in my results with the expected most recent datetime.   So I stripped my query down the basics:

NOTE that **the real-life query does not look at custID**.  I am including it here to narrow down on the problem.

```
        SELECT
            el.eventID,
            el.custID,
            el.date_event
        FROM  
            event_log el
        WHERE 
            el.custID = 12345 AND
            el.userID=987
        GROUP BY  
            el.custID
        HAVING
            MAX( el.eventID )
```

This is returned:

```
eventID     custID  date_event
346290      12345   2013-06-21 09:58:44
```

Here's the EXPLAIN

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys               key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE          el      ref     userID,custID,Composite     custID  5           const   203     Using where
```

If I change the query to use HAVING MIN, the results don't change.. I should see a different eventID and date_event, as there are dozens of records matching the custID and userID.

```
        SELECT
            el.eventID,
            el.custID,
            el.date_event
        FROM  
            event_log el
        WHERE 
            el.custID = 12345 AND
            el.userID=987
        GROUP BY  
            el.custID
        HAVING
            MIN( el.eventID )
```

Same results as before:

```
eventID     custID  date_event
346290      12345   2013-06-21 09:58:44
```

No change.

This tells me I have another problem, but I am not seeing what that might be.

Some pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Your usage of `group by` is invalid SQL which is rejected by all other DBMS. But MySQL accepts it and simply choses to return random data to you. Read this http://rpbouman.blogspot.de/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html and this http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/ to understand why

Comment: @Aiias, ORDER BY is applied to results after any filtering is done.  Won't work.

Comment: Also, because you're not comparing the `HAVING MIN( el.eventID )` to a value, it's saying the same thing as `el.eventID IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieving the last record in each group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
    el.eventID,
    el.custID,
    el.date_event
FROM  
    event_log el
WHERE 
    el.custID = 12345 AND
    el.userID=987 AND
    el.eventID IN (SELECT MAX(eventID)
                   FROM event_log
                   WHERE custID = 12345
                   AND userID = 987)
```

Your query doesn't work because you misunderstand what `HAVING` does. It evaluates the expression on each line of the result set, and keeps the rows where the expression evaluates to true. The expression `MAX(el.eventID)` simply returns the maximum event ID selected by the query, it doesn't compare the current row to that event ID.

Another way is:

```
SELECT
    el.eventID,
    el.custID,
    el.date_event
FROM  
    event_log el
WHERE 
    el.custID = 12345 AND
    el.userID=987
ORDER BY eventID DESC
LIMIT 1
```

The more general form that works for multiple custID is:

```
SELECT el.*
FROM event_log el
JOIN (SELECT custID, max(date_event) maxdate
      FROM event_log
      WHERE userID = 987
      GROUP BY custID) emax
ON el.custID = emax.custID AND el.date_event = emax.maxdate
WHERE el.userID = 987
```

Comment: There are multiple rows for the passed custID/userID.  The second query would return one row (correct data), however the actual query is custID non-specific.  The second example would only work where there is one row (custID) for that userID.  In real life, there would be dozens.   The first example (above) works as expected, but I haven't modified it to remove the custID criteria.

Comment: How can the second query return all rows when it uses `LIMIT 1`?

Comment: Things get more complicated when you want to do this for multiple custIDs -- the right way is with a join. There are lots of SO questions that show the way to get the maximum row for each group.

Comment: I am using a join and it works perfect now.  Thanks.  `   SELECT
    ev1.eventID,
    ev1.custID,
    ev1.date_event
   FROM  
    event_log ev1
    LEFT JOIN event_log ev2 ON ev1.emory_id = ev2.emory_id AND ev1.userID = ev2.userID AND ev1.date_event < ev2.date_event
   WHERE 
    el.custID = 12345 AND
    el.userID=987 AND
    ev2.emory_id IS NULL`

Comment: Still a minor problem when I remove the custID clause (two rows for each custID are returned), but I think I'm good from here. thanks again.

Comment: See the more general query I just added.

Comment: +1 for your explaination of HAVING. I misunderstood HAVING as a pre-selector of the result set prior to GROUP BY. Now I've learned I can use WHERE to filter data set prior to GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a group function in a statement containing no GROUP BY clause, but it would be equivalent to grouping on all rows. But I guess you're looking for the common syntax,

```
SELECT
  MIN(el.eventID) AS `min_eventID`, --> Yes it is wrong :(
  el.custID,
  el.date_event
FROM  
  event_log el
WHERE 
  el.userID = 987
GROUP BY el.custID;
```

But disagreements are welcome .

---

#### [ Edit ]

I think I didn't show a solution fast enough... but maybe you're rather looking for the fastest solution.
Assuming field *date_event* defaults to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP (am I wrong?), ordering by date_event would be a waste of time (and money, thus).
I've made some tests with 20K rows and execution time was about 5ms.

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN y.*
FROM ((
  SELECT MAX(eventId) as eventId
  FROM event_log
  WHERE userId = 987 AND custId = 12345
)) AS x
INNER JOIN event_log AS y
  USING (eventId);
```

---

Maybe (possibly, who knows) you didn't get the straight_join thing; as documented on the [scriptures](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html), STRAIGHT_JOINs are similar to JOINs, except that the left table is always read before the right table. Sometimes it's useful.
For your specific situation, we're likely to filter to a certain eventID before (on table "x"), not to retrieve 99,99% useless rows from table "y".

- More disagreements expected in 3, 2, ...

Comment: This doesn't select the date that goes with that event ID.